# Is UncaughtExceptionHandler customized by SmartGWT?

Tags: smartgwt

I see that the JavaScript exceptions are not thrown to the browser of sample SmartGWT application. But the same is thrown by a plain GWT app.

All I did was created a GWT Test App and made a scenario to throw nullpointer exception. Firefox/Chrome/IE threw the exception in the browser console.

For eg.,

```
Label testLabel = null;
testLabel.setText("Welcome")
```

With the same app, I created SmartGWT widget and created a scenario to throw a nullpointer exception, but the exception was not thrown to the browser console.

For Eg.,

```
com.smartgwt.client.widgets.Window testWindow = null;
testWindow.setTitle("Welcome....");
```

My assumption was any uncaught exception should be handed over to the browser. Wondering if anyone know more details about it ?

Comment: which version of smart gwt you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the version below 2.4 .its fixed in 2.4

Yes .. this woohaa  behavior is there  but fixed.

```
This has been resolved for a while now on mainline. Please try the latest nighty build from http://smartclient.com/builds

The fix will be in the soon to be released Smart GWT 2.4.
```

Reference

http://code.google.com/p/smartgwt/issues/detail?id=533

Comment: Unfortunately am using 2.4. Not sure why the RunTimeException not being thrown to the browser. Let me look at this reference and let you know if i find anything useful.